# Plot errors from matplotlib and pylab when attempting to plot mat (Matlab) files

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I need some help when attempting to plot .mat files (Matlab) using scipy.sio.
Not sure what else I need to do the data to be able to plot. I hope the reader can follow what I have pasted below.

### I typed as follows:

```
import scipy as sio

mat_contents = sio.loadmat('abc.mat')

sio.whosmat('abc.mat')
```

**Result =**

```
[('**ctrllef**t', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('ctrlright', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('ioleft', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('ioright', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('faultleft', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('faultright', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('validleft', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('validright', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('ovdleft', (1, 1), 'struct'),
 ('ovdright', (1, 1), 'struct')]

mat_a = mat_contents['**ctrlleft**']

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

pp.plot(mat_a, mat_contents, 'x')

**Result =**  ValueError: Can't cast from structure to non-structure, except if the structure only has a single field

from pylab import *

from matplotlib import *

matshow(mat_a)
```

**Result =**  `TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float`

Answer (score 0):

Based on `('**ctrllef**t', (1, 1), 'struct')` I'd say that `mat_a` is a (1,1) object dtype array.  `mat_a.item()` is probably a structured array, with one field for each attribute of the MATLAB `struct` object.  Fields of such an array are accessed by name.

Often I just do `ipython` display (repr print) of `mat_contents`, or if that's too big, of `mat_a.item()`.  `mat_a.item().dtype` will also be a useful display, as would be its `.shape`.

One way or other you need to work your way down the data structure produced by `loadmat` until you get `ndarray` that you can pass to the `plot`.  Without knowing more about the MATLAB data structures I can't predict what `mat_contents` is like.  And even then I find it easier to explore that object interactively in a `numpy` session.

The type of object that `loadmat` produces has been discussed in many previous SO questions.  Since the MATLAB source varies we can only give general guidelines.

A recent example of passing a MATLAB `struct` to/from `numpy`:

[How can I create a Matlab file from Python with multi-dimensional arrays in a Matlab data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729464/how-can-i-create-a-matlab-file-from-python-with-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-a-ma)

Comment: When I type 'mat_a.item().dtype', the error message I get is AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'.

Can you please explain what you mean by 'you need to work your way down the data structure produced by loadmat until you get ndarray that you can pass to the plot'?

Thanks for taking the time to reply hpaulj.

Comment: So are you going to leave me guessing as to what's the content of that `tuple`.  You have the file and data, I don't.  I can only guess based on past experience with `mat` files and SO questions.  There isn't a one-to-one match between MATLAB structures and `numpy` ones.

Comment: I am just learning python .. but this is what I got. I hope this is what you're looking for.

np.where(mat_a)

Out[26]: (array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))

Comment: It might be simpler if you went into MATLAB and saved a new file with just a few matrices that you want to plot.  The match between matrices and numpy arrays is simpler.

Comment: I will try what you suggested. Thanks again for your help.